# Browse site which requires logged info

Tags: c#, session, cookies, httpwebrequest

I have been trying to get it working for hours with little success. From source after first request I can see that login was successful, but using cookies to access other keeps asking for login info.

Here is site which I'm trying to access: http://gpro.net/

And here is the code I'm using:
            string formUrl = "http://gpro.net/pl/Login.asp?langCode=pl&Redirect=gpro.asp"; // NOTE: This is the URL the form POSTs to, not the URL of the form (you can find this in the "action" attribute of the HTML's form tag
            string formParams = "textLogin=user&textPassword=pass&Logon=Login&LogonFake=Sign+in";

```
        string strResponse;
        HttpWebRequest requestLogin = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        requestLogin.Method = "POST";
        requestLogin.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        requestLogin.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        requestLogin.ContentLength = formParams.Length;
        StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(requestLogin.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        stOut.Write(formParams);
        stOut.Close();

        HttpWebResponse responseLogin = (HttpWebResponse)requestLogin.GetResponse();
        StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(responseLogin.GetResponseStream());
        strResponse = stIn.ReadToEnd();
        stIn.Close();
        sb.Append(strResponse);
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine();
        //Add cookies to CookieJar (Cookie Container)
        foreach (Cookie cookie in responseLogin.Cookies)
        {
            cookieJar.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name.Trim(), cookie.Value.Trim(), cookie.Path, cookie.Domain));
            sb.AppendLine(cookie.Name.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + cookie.Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + cookie.Path.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + cookie.Domain.ToString());
        }

        //Grab the cookie we just got back for this specifc page

        string cookies = cookieJar.GetCookieHeader(requestLogin.RequestUri);


        //put it back in the cookie container for the whole server

        cookieJar.SetCookies(new Uri("http://www.gpro.net/"), cookies);

        string testResults = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest runTest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.gpro.net/pl/RaceAnalysis.asp");
        runTest.Referer = "http://gpro.net/pl/gpro.asp";
        runTest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        //runTest.Method = "POST";
        //runTest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //StreamWriter stOut2 = new StreamWriter(runTest.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        //stOut2.Write(formParams);
        //stOut2.Close();
        StreamReader stIn2 = new StreamReader(runTest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        testResults = stIn2.ReadToEnd();
        stIn2.Close();
        sb.Append(testResults);
        e.Result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Cookies are not set until the NEXT Http request .....

Comment: What do you mean ? In this line: string cookies = cookieJar.GetCookieHeader(requestLogin.RequestUri);

cookieJar already contains 4 cookies (same as firebug reports). Problem is it is not using them in next request: http://www.gpro.net/pl/RaceAnalysis.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong with code above and every similar one posted in stack overflow (I have tried all marked as working). When I was logging with browser redirection worked fine, with but using above method my request was redirected to same address, but without www prefix. That resulted with two different cookies collections. I removed www prefix from every request which solved login problem.